# Bind access dataset to a combobox using access database Vb.net

Tags: .net

I have a database in access called mydata. Within it is a table called **Department** . Components of the department database include : id, class and name

I want to bind a combobox to the department table. I however want the *name* of the department table to appear

Well, I am new to vb

Comment: Since you didnt show any code i can show you in whicu direction you should go. Look for command to fill your combobox. Watch for combobox property ValueMember and displaymember.

Comment: @programerAnel thanks bro... it worked

Comment: Since you didnt write any code this was only way to go